# how do i add two Json data Iin c# mvc 5

Tags: c#

How do i add two json value in c#.

here is the code:

```
 dynamic notifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results);

Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatepersonal) + Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatesaas) + Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatependingaction);
```

Comment: how does notifications look like?

Answer (score 0):

By putting the .Value keyword behind the property you want:

```
var weee = Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatepersonal.Value) + Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatesaas.Value) + Convert.ToInt32(notifications.pensionleads.Associateleads.associatependingaction.Value);
```

Probably should also write a function to check if it exists/has value in your object first if you are not 100% sure it will always be there and always have a value.